# Microsoft Graph $filter returns "Invalid filter clause" on /beta/me/chats requests

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

Using the [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer/preview) a GET request of

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/chats?$expand=members&$filter=members/any(o: o/displayname eq 'Steve Ratcliffe')
```

succeeds, however a GET request of

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/chats?$expand=members&$filter=members/any(o: o/email eq 'steve@ratcliffe.com')
```

fails with an error 400 - "Invalid filter clause". The same errors occurs when trying to filter by `userId`.

How can one make `email` or `userId` filters work on chats?

Comment: Not all properties support filter query parameter as of now, like this for example. If you want to filter by email or userId, you should do it on your end(by writing code). You can raise a feature request to include these properties as well to filter on the [Microsoft Graph Feedback Forum](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests) so that the product team may develop it in future.

Comment: @Shiva-MSFTIdentity How do you know that those parameters are not supported in filter query? It's not mentioned in graph api doc and error "Invalid filter clause" it too general.